# Why following regex code crash in VC++ 2013 debug mode

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++

Why the following code crashes in VC++ Debug mode but works in Release mode

[image]

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    auto P = std::regex(R"(^([^\x00]*?)$)");
    std::smatch M;
    if (std::regex_search(std::string("A"), M, P)){
        std::cout << M[0].str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can declare a separate `std::string s("A")` variable  and pass it as the first argument to `regex_search`. Then, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GCC and Clang this code just [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6074bbc1125527d4), as well as in VS2015. The reason is that since C++14 [`std::regex_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) is prohibited to take temporary string as an argument, because otherwise it would fill match results with invalid iterators.

VS2013 is obviously not C++14-compliant, so you are allowed to make that invalid call. So `M[0]` contains invalid iterators and trying to call `str()` on it invokes undefined behavior.

In Debug you are lucky enough and catch some assert in the string iterator code, but it might not even be the case.

Comment: I cannot compile OP code in VS2012 either.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't have VS2012, but I believe that for it the reason is different, probably lack of support for `regex`.

Comment: No, it does support regex, it [does not support raw string literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx). When I remove the `R` with the outer delimiters, it runs and throws the same  exception as OP gets.